# Matlab Grid Generator

Tags: matlab

The following is a Matlab code that I got from my Numerical Analysis Textbook. It is used to discretize a Laplacian and setup a matrix based on the chosen domain(in this case a unit square). I was wondering how this code could be modified to change the dimensions of the domain. I.e. a 4 x 5 rectangle. I don't really use Matlab much, but I am curious to see the results for different domains.

```
N = nx * ny;  
N5 = 5 * N;
irow = zeros(N5, 1);
icol = irow; 
NZA = irow;

index = 0;
row = 0;

for j = 1:ny
   for k = 1:nx

      row = row + 1;

      if j > 1
         index = index + 1;
         NZA (index) = -1.0;
         irow(index) = row;
         icol(index) = row - nx;   % South
      end

      if k > 1
         index = index + 1;
         NZA (index) = -1.0;
         irow(index) = row;
         icol(index) = row - 1;    % West
      end

      index = index + 1;
      NZA (index) = 4.0;
      irow(index) = row;
      icol(index) = row;           % P (self)

      if k < nx
         index = index + 1;
         NZA (index) = -1.0;
         irow(index) = row;
         icol(index) = row + 1;    % East
      end

      if j < ny 
         index = index + 1;
         NZA (index) = -1.0;
         irow(index) = row;
         icol(index) = row + nx;   % North
      end
   end
end            

icol = icol(1:index); 
irow = irow(1:index);
NZA = NZA(1:index);

A = sparse (irow, icol, NZA, N, N);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Please tell in words what you want to achieve instead of posting the entire code. Do you want to generate a grid in MATLAB of arbitrary size?

Comment: How can I modify the code to alter the dimensions of the grid that it is creating? For example, a 4 x 5 rectangle instead of the unit square.

Comment: Why don't you use `meshgrid` from MATALB? I haven't ran above code so I don't know exactly what it does. You can give an input and an output for the above code to make the question clearer.

Comment: The output is a 16 x 16 Matrix, generated from the grid, which happens to be a unit square for how the code is currently constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can change the size by setting nx and ny.

Comment: No doubt! No criticism here. :) p1

Comment: I actually ran the code and discovered it the first time, but never thought the OP was asking for such a simple thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about modifying the above code, but I think you can get a `mxn` grid of points representing a [unit square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_square) as follows:

```
%user input
m=4; % points in x-direction
n=5; %points in y-direction

%code
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:1/m:1,0:1/n:1);

%visualization
allPointsOnGrid=[x(:) y(:)];
scatter(allPointsOnGrid(:,1),allPointsOnGrid(:,2));
```

This will generate a unit square with `m+1` points in x-direction and `n+1` points in y-direction.